# Scoping SQL to a bounding box over the international date line

Tags: sql, geolocation, gis, latitude-longitude, bounding-box

I'm trying to scope my query to select locations that are within a bounding box of latitudes/longitudes. Generally this works fine given the bounding box doesn't cross the international date line.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM locations
WHERE latitude BETWEEN ? AND ?
AND longitude BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

However - if my bounding box was to cross the international date line - say longitudinal bounds of `179.00` to `-179.00` then the query returns no results. I can't just flip the order and change it to between `-179.00` and `179.00` because that would instead return things outside of my bounding box.

What is the sanest way to best determine the appropriate SQL required (either as SQL or psuedocode that would help derive the best SQL).

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Are your locations stored in some kind of geo data type?

Comment: +1 to RDBMS question. Some databases have native spatial support, that you can use. E.g. BigQuery has `ST_IntersectsBox` which works correctly across international date line, e.g. `ST_IntersectsBox(p, 179, -10, -179, 10)`.

Comment: I am using MySQL but with latitude/longitude stored as separate double columns.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that you could do is use `CASE WHEN` expressions in the `WHERE` clause to distinguish whether your lower longitudinal bound is larger than the upper one and  modify the behavior accordingly:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM locations 
 WHERE lon BETWEEN CASE WHEN @param1 > @param2 THEN -180.0 
                        ELSE @param1 
                   END AND @param2 
    OR lon BETWEEN CASE WHEN @param1 > @param2 THEN @param1 
                        ELSE 181.0 
                   END AND 180.0
```

For your example (longitudinal bounds of `179.00` to `-179.00`), this will have same the effect as

```
SELECT * 
  FROM locations 
 WHERE lon BETWEEN -180.0 AND -179.0
    OR lon BETWEEN 179.0 AND 180.0
```

while the same query for the inverted example (longitudinal bounds of `-179.00` to `179.00`) will evaluate to

```
SELECT * 
  FROM locations 
 WHERE lon BETWEEN -179.0 AND 179.0
    OR lon BETWEEN 181.0 AND 180.0 -- (always false)
```

See it in action in [this db<>fiddle (SQL Server example)](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=60da47f3cc926c7117215ee010fee197).

Comment: I like where this is going - I think it's a good blueprint to translate into some code that could generate SQL without the always falsely OR clause.